# Multiprocessing set class attribute values in differential evolution

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, multiprocessing, differential-evolution

I am doing optimization using `differential_evolution`.
I use a `class` where I want to update the attribute values after each iteration, and use the attribute values from the last iteration to do some calculation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

class Model:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.p1 = np.array([])
        self.p2 = np.array([])
    
    def post(self, x):
        pp = x[0] * self.p1 / self.p2
        print("pp:", pp)

    def likelihood(params):
        ....
        p1 = ...
        p2 = ...
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        return -ll


model=Model(data)
results = differential_evolution(model.likelihood, seed=np.random.seed(0),workers=10)
model.post(results.x)
```

And I get

```
pp: []
```

`workers=10` enables `multiprocessing` which (I guess) cannot set a class's attribute values.

How can I get `p1` and `p2` from the last iteration?

Comment: Multiprocessing deals with processes. Each process operates in its own memory space (no shared memory by default). Classes are pickled and sent to processes. The modified version is not sent back. Even if it was, you would get a *race condition* because of parallelism. This means the approach is certainly flawed. You can create a queue and manually send the value back to the main thread but this is cumbersome to to. Shared memory cannot be easily applied here because of classes (more generally all Python objects need to be pickled and only native types can benefit from shared memory).

Comment: If you want to modify the content of `p1` and `p2` and not the reference (as it is currently done), then shared memory can work. But you still need to fix the race condition before anyway (and possibly use locks for the shared accesses to be safe).